# compare two text files via php but find diffrence

Tags: php

I have 2 text files

**a.txt**

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
5555
```

**b.txt**

```
6666
1111
7777
8888
2222
9999
```

I am running this script

```
$lines1 = file("a.txt");
$data2 = file_get_contents("b.txt");

foreach($lines1 as $line1){
$line1 = trim($line1);

if(strpos($data2, $line1)){
echo $line1;
echo "<br />";
}
}
```

code working it list all lines from a.txt which are available in b.txt

but i need inverse of this code.I want it shows only that is not available on b.tx

Comment: For not available use `if(!strpos($data2, $line1)){`

Comment: nope, "!strpos($data2, $line1)" returns false for 0;
so, "( strpos($data2, $line1) === false )" should be used

Comment: thanks .................... : )

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of [existing components](https://packagist.org/search/?q=diff), which allows you to compute the difference between text files.

Don't try to reinvent the wheel, use proven, mature, existing code to speed up your development with confidence.

Comment: One does not exclude the other. You are probably not familiar with the Composer then? Whats more verbose and dead simple - examples below or $diff = Diff::compare('file1', 'file2');

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines1 = file("a.txt");
$data2 = file_get_contents("b.txt");

foreach($lines1 as $line1){
$line1 = trim($line1);

if(!strpos($data2, $line1)){
echo $line1;
echo "<br />";
}
}
```

//// Saty i did it .... it works (well Alex Babak i save your code also if another project i will try )

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$lines1 = file( 'a.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
$lines2 = file( 'b.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );

$result = array_diff( $lines1, $lines2 );
print_r( $result );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 3333
    [3] => 4444
    [4] => 5555
)
```

With the flag `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`, [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) strips newlines for you, so you don't need to trim array values.

[`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) subtracts elements of `$lines2` from `$lines1`.

If you want save (or print) the result in a newline-delimited text, use

```
$text = implode( "\n", $result );
```

---

- Read more about [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)
- Read more about [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)
- Read more about [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)